# Old C Code Transmogrifier*

Tags: code-golf, string

<sup>[*What is a transmogrifier?](http://calvinandhobbes.wikia.com/wiki/Transmogrifier)</sup>

In the [C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), there are formations called [digraphs and trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C) that are two and three characters sequences that evaluate to less common characters. For example, you can use `??-` if your keyboard doesn't have `~`.

Given text, replace all instances of the following digraphs and trigraphs (left side) with the correct, shorter, golfed character (right side).

```
??=  #
??/  \
??'  ^
??(  [
??)  ]
??!  |
??<  {
??>  }
??-  ~
<:   [
:>   ]
<%   {
%>   }
%:   #
```

<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C)</sup>

## Input

Input is ASCII text. Trailing newline allowed. Does not need to be valid C code.

## Output

Output is the same text, with all instances of the above digraphs and trigraphs replaced with the shortened version, evaluated left to right. Trailing newline allowed. Does not need to be valid C code.

## Test Cases

`=>` separates input and output.

```
if (true ??!??! false) { => if (true || false) {

??-arr.indexOf(n) => ~arr.indexOf(n)

function f(??) { console.log('test??'); } => function f(] { console.log('test^); }

/* comment :> :) *??/ => /* comment ] :) *\

%:What am I doing??!!??` => `#What am I doing|!??

??(??)??(??) <:-- not a palindrome => [][] [-- not a palindrome

?????????? => ??????????

int f(int??(??) a) ??< return a??(0??)??'a??(1??) + "??/n"; ??> => int f(int[] a) { return a[0]^a[1] + "\n"; }

??<:>??<% => {]{%

<:> => [>

<::> => []

:>> => ]>

#\^[]|{}~ => #\^[]|{}~

: > => : >

??=%: => ##
```

Comment: Please remove the `s from the examples. It makes them so hard to read.

Comment: `"??=%:"` is another relevant test case: in C, this means `"#%:"` where `%:` isn't special, but I think your expected output is `"##"`.

Comment: @Satan'sSon will do, I originally had it not in a code block to make input/output more readable but Riker changed it over. Feel free to edit something like formatting yourself next time :)

Comment: So, you're asking for golfed code to golf code. Bonus golf :-)

Comment: @Mast that's the idea

Comment: I just learned something about PHP...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 65 bytes

```
T`-=/'()!<>?`~#\\^[]|{}_`\?\?[-=/'()!<>]
<:
[
:>
]
<%
{
>%
}
%:
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#PZBBb4MwDIXv/hVuEYJ0oqzXlMXnnXaZtEPpRtSGDgmSKQRpEqN/nZmtW5Q8WfHL@yLPz1X2kCepWBWKqmtUlq@H49c4vVUllXT47x2hkHAAqYCrGEZQMUwQS4jmuakxDX4wSLTijbVueyNwBKJMe79t7Nl8PtWpFVAP9hQaZ7FOidiCJ2d715pt6y5pEkwfiBKxxwnyDfe6ztiAUqEUuCHKGfjyrgPqDh/x7Bp7YR4zmbTk/SoWMsvQOrbhh26Z7l1n2PK3oOHQOmW9PdCCv16gN2HwFjXf3v@kJUu5Wxx3uGa8Xe/ZqDiqkIol5qEoPixSKYhus7uCRPUN) `T` is a little awkward to use but still saves me 14 bytes.

Comment: Can you do `\?\?[^:%]`?

Comment: (`\?\?[^:%?]` rather)

Comment: @ETHproductions That would have a side effect of also turning `??a` into `a`.

Comment: @eush77 Oh hmm, you're right...

Comment: Line 8 should be `%>` instead of `>%`.

Comment: @Dennis Ugh, that means rewriting the entire post...

Comment: It does? What else depends on line 8?

Comment: @Dennis The TIO link uses an old format, and I don't know how to tweak the link to switch the characters over, so I'd have to start with a new TIO autogenerated block.

Answer (score 7):

## C, <del>206</del> 205 bytes

(-1 thanks to ceilingcat)

The newlines are just here for readability.

```
c,d,q;f(char*s){for(char*S,*T,*t=s;c-63?q=0:q++,d=c<<8|*s,*s?
q>1&&(T=index(S="=/'()!<>-",*s))?t-=2,*s="#\\^[]|{}~"[T-S]:
d>*s&&(T=strstr(S=">:<>%<:%",&d))&&(c="][ }{ # "[T-S])&1?--t,*s=c:0:
0,*t++=c=*s++;);}
```

Modifies `s` in place. Tested with GCC and clang on Fedora Workstation, x86, in 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

C is not exactly the best language for golfing here.

Comment: `C is not exactly the best language for golfing here.` no kidding. Looks good :) Thinking back, I should have forced all questions to add +1 or +2 bytes if they used one of the characters that a digraph or trigraph makes xD

Comment: You could make it even worse: +1 or +2 for each character that can be part of a di-/trigraph would really hurt :)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 106 bytes

```js
s=>[...'#\\^[]|{}~[]{}#'].map((c,i)=>s=s.split('<:<%%'[i-9]+':>%>:'[i-9]||'??'+"=/'()!<>-"[i]).join(c))&&s
```

#### How?

This is pretty straightforward.

We should note however that:

- When **i** is less than **9**, the expression `'<:<%%'[i-9] + ':>%>:'[i-9]` evaluates to `undefined + undefined` which equals `NaN` (falsy as expected).
- When **i** is greater than or equal to **9**, the expression `'??' + "=/'()!<>-"[i]` evaluates to `"??" + undefined` which is coerced to the string `"??undefined"` (truthy when we expect a falsy result).

That's why we must process the test in this order.

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>[...'#\\^[]|{}~[]{}#'].map((c,i)=>s=s.split('<:<%%'[i-9]+':>%>:'[i-9]||'??'+"=/'()!<>-"[i]).join(c))&&s

console.log(f(`if (true ??!??! false) {`))                                        // `if (true || false) {`
console.log(f(`??-arr.indexOf(n)`))                                               // `~arr.indexOf(n)`
console.log(f(`function f(??) { console.log('test??'); }`))                       // `function f(] { console.log('test^); }`
console.log(f(`/* comment :> :) *??/`))                                           // `/* comment ] :) *\`
console.log(f(`%:What am I doing??!!??`))                                         // `#What am I doing|!??`
console.log(f(`??(??)??(??) <:-- not a palindrome`))                              // `[][] [-- not a palindrome`
console.log(f(`??????????`))                                                      // `??????????`
console.log(f(`int f(int??(??) a) ??< return a??(0??)??'a??(1??) + "??/n"; ??>`)) // `int f(int[] a) { return a[0]^a[1] + "\n"; }`
console.log(f(`??<:>??<%`))                                                       // `{]{%`
console.log(f(`<:>`))                                                             // `[>`
console.log(f(`<::>`))                                                            // `[]`
console.log(f(`:>>`))                                                             // `]>`
console.log(f(`#\^[]|{}~`))                                                       // `#\^[]|{}~`
console.log(f(`: >`))                                                             // `: >`
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP , 112 Bytes

```php
<?=str_replace(explode(_,strtr("<:_:>_<%_%>_%:0=0/0'0(0)0!0<0>0-",["_??"])),str_split("[]{}##\\^[]|{}~"),$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#Hc5LCoMwFEbheXdhbDABxTtOb/IvRO1FWmkL0obooGDt1u1jeuCDw4jXuNv36XL3CvBADRSAASyQAQwEoGLnAmsdtFMHhI3hpzlJGuLYnwYzPOP4OA9Gym@dk1HsxAVhLTqIduSppoIMWcqIKVClykYJoDprf0SmON5mo5puWfO8bY9N91rWt7Ll/8wetu0D)

### PHP , 115 Bytes

```php
<?=str_replace(explode(_,"??=_??/_??'_??(_??)_??!_??<_??>_??-_<:_:>_<%_%>_%:"),str_split("#\\^[]|{}~[]{}#"),$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#Hc7BCoJAFIXhfW@hNjgDSvvxes@DqF2khgqkBnURmL26XVt8qwM/hxDv8XDsx9uzToEaOAE5YAEHJAABDJTkPZMxbHxagTdCPc2jjCEO/SXY8I7D6xqsFHtDNKJyZZVTiSLFqhTy4lnIiGHRoCv21hSHx2zTrG3PTfdZ1m/TLWum4/@cq7btBw)

### PHP , 124 Bytes

Regex solution

```
foreach(explode(_,"=|%:_/_'_\(|<:_\)|:>_!_<|<%_>|%>_-")as$v)$a=preg_replace("#\?\?$v#","#\\^[]|{}~"[$k++],$a=&$argn);echo$a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#Hc7RDoIgGIbh8@5CgoRp6xyB70LE/jEj3XLJbGttUbdurrP34Dl4DdKYdjwsw90ywAInoAQkoIACMIADjkZrZ4RwQrNmvc5LDP0o4ytN8yVKqpnNQtOJSvIyG01eZe2oIJONIJeFoyNT4cGfigebljjQEtMU@ijZ3sODP/es3tKf2y6/P1/W8ltVdfWmD/851cR@nHlo1vUH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 104+1 = 105 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag for +1 byte.

```ruby
"=#/\\'^([)]!|<{>}-~".scan(/(.)(.)/){|k,v|gsub'??'+k,v}
"<:[:>]<%{%>}%:#".scan(/(..)(.)/){|k,v|gsub k,v}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#ZU5Lc4MgEL7zKzY6jpBUba/EwrmnHnswyQwxaJ0qZBA77aj56@nax@RQZvmA5XtsuHLD8ROS8zV4DLPdLj7Qgu1XUz6KObkEaV8qQzOaMqyMjdPb3ftU98MxljLe4GMmQc4LLvZ5NEZijnh40/wTwSK4XpsKqHeDBilXWFCpttcMRiJlopxLG3PSH88VNYxUgyl9Yw1UVEqkQGlNb1udtramsde9xznYFmaSrfGv67TxwAVwBmspMxLxl1flQXXwBCfbmBrzMBOTFr8fhJwnCRiLNDirFtOd7TRS/hZp0LSiiL8CxXD0HJz2gzOgsHv/7RYv14eFsYEA402wRaJAq5wLhIjgiRuBC0HC3aHYT@N8IRzEFw)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), <strike>131</strike> 123 bytes

```js
f=
s=>"#??= \\??/ ^??' [??( ]??) |??! {??< {??> ~??- [<: ]:> {<% }%> #%:".split` `.map(x=>s=s.split(x.slice(1)).join(x[0]))&&s
```

```html
<input oninput=console.log(f(this.value))>
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 113 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/\?\?[^:%?]|[<:%]./g,c=>"#\\^[]|{}~"["=/'()!<>-".indexOf(c[2])]||"[] {} #"["<:><%>%:".indexOf(c)]||c)
```

Not the shortest, but I wanted to try a different approach.